# i have a margin on the left of my site and i dont know how to get rid of it or where it came from

Tags: html, css

hey guys I am making a mobile version of my site and on the left side of my grid containers, I have some white margin. When the scope is for a desktop the grid is in the center. What I want is for my grid to be on the far left. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}

header {
  padding: 0 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #28352f;
}

.greet {
  background: #fff url(background.png) no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.hi-there {
  margin-right: 2.8em;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 52px;
  color: #172b4d;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.text-box {
  margin-top: 3em;
}

.hi-there2 {
  color: #36b37f;
  margin-top: 1.7em;
  margin-right: 2em;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 52px;
  margin-right: 2.8em;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.paragraph1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 2em 24px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #172b4d;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.icon-row {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 3px;
}

li {
  margin: 8px;
  list-style: none;
}

.grid-containers {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.container {
  width: 327px;
  height: 474px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  border-color: #d0d9d4;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  align-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.column1 {
  background-color: #d0d9d4;
}

.column2 {
  background-color: white;
}

.languages li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.ruby {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ebf0ee;
  padding: 8px;
}

.css {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ebf0ee;
  padding: 6px;
}

.js {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ebf0ee;
  padding: 6px;
}

.html {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ebf0ee;
  padding: 6px;
}

.ruby:hover {
  text-decoration: underline rgb(6, 14, 243);
  border: 1px solid rgb(6, 14, 243);
}

.css:hover {
  text-decoration: underline rgb(6, 14, 243);
  border: 1px solid rgb(6, 14, 243);
}

.js:hover {
  text-decoration: underline rgb(6, 14, 243);
  border: 1px solid rgb(6, 14, 243);
}

.html:hover {
  text-decoration: underline rgb(6, 14, 243);
  border: 1px solid rgb(6, 14, 243);
}

.project-name1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #3a4a42;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.project-name-two {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #3a4a42;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="/" class="header-logo">
        <h3>Welcome</h3>
      </a>
      <nav>
        <img src="Union.png" alt="menu link" />
      </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="greet">
      <div class="text-box">
        <h1 class="hi-there">Hey there. I’m <br />David</h1>
        <h2 class="hi-there2">
          I’m a software <br /> developer
        </h2>
      </div>

      <p class="paragraph1">
        I can help you build a product , feature or website Look through some of my work and experience! If you like what you see and have a project you need coded, don’t hestiate to contact me.
      </p>



      <ul class="icon-row">
        <li>
          <div class="tweet-connect">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/david630"><img class="tweet" src="twitter.svg" alt="twitter picture" /></a>
        </li>


        <li>
          <img class="med" src="medium.svg" alt="medium picture" />

        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="https://github.com/david63011"><img class="git" src="github.svg" alt="git picture" /></a>
        </li>


        <li>
          <img class="angel" src="angellist.svg" alt="angelist picture" />

        </li>

        <section class="grid-containers">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="column1"></div>
            <div class="column2">
              <div class="project-box">
                <h1 class="project-name1">Multi-Post Stories</h1>
                <h1 class="project-name-two">Gain+Glory</h1>
              </div>

              <div class="languages">
                <ul>
                  <li class="ruby">Ruby on Rails</li>
                  <li class="css">css</li>
                  <li class="js">JavScript</li>
                  <li class="html">HTML</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="see-project-btn">See Project</button>
            </div>
          </div>



  </body>

</html>
```

I have tried removing the margin and padding but I am not sure what exactaly i can do ot fix this problem

Comment: Lint your html code first. I see so many unclosed tags and two <body> tags. https://www.atatus.com/tools/html-lint

Comment: hey my html is shown above

Comment: thanks i removed it but is didnt help. My grid element is still in the middle of the page and in the mobile scope it has around a one inch margin

Comment: close </ul> before section. I suggest you use a good IDE like vscode.

Comment: thanks, Behrouz that solved a different problem I was having but i still have the problem that my grid is in the center of the page and not on the left

Comment: my first guess would be the multiple "margin-right" in the css.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you need to focus on to improve your code:

- try to do the job with minimum css
- check to see if you have closed the tags you've opened
- avoid nested elements as much as possible

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
}

header {
  padding: 0 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #28352f;
}

.greet {
  background: #fff url(background.png) no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.hi-there {
  margin-right: 2.8em;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 52px;
  color: #172b4d;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.text-box {
  margin-top: 3em;
}

.hi-there2 {
  color: #36b37f;
  margin-top: 1.7em;
  margin-right: 2em;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 52px;
  margin-right: 2.8em;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.paragraph1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 2em 24px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #172b4d;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.icon-row {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 3px;
}

li {
  margin: 8px;
  list-style: none;
}

.grid-containers {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.container {
  width: 327px;
  height: 474px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  border-color: #d0d9d4;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  align-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.column1 {
  background-color: #d0d9d4;
}

.column2 {
  background-color: white;
}

.languages li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.ruby {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ebf0ee;
  padding: 8px;
}

.css {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ebf0ee;
  padding: 6px;
}

.js {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ebf0ee;
  padding: 6px;
}

.html {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ebf0ee;
  padding: 6px;
}

.ruby:hover {
  text-decoration: underline rgb(6, 14, 243);
  border: 1px solid rgb(6, 14, 243);
}

.css:hover {
  text-decoration: underline rgb(6, 14, 243);
  border: 1px solid rgb(6, 14, 243);
}

.js:hover {
  text-decoration: underline rgb(6, 14, 243);
  border: 1px solid rgb(6, 14, 243);
}

.html:hover {
  text-decoration: underline rgb(6, 14, 243);
  border: 1px solid rgb(6, 14, 243);
}

.project-name1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #3a4a42;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.project-name-two {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #3a4a42;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="/" class="header-logo">
    <h3>Welcome</h3>
  </a>
  <nav>
    <img src="Union.png" alt="menu link" />
  </nav>
</header>
<section class="greet">
  <div class="text-box">
    <h1 class="hi-there">Hey there. I’m <br />David</h1>
    <h2 class="hi-there2">
      I’m a software <br /> developer
    </h2>
  </div>

  <p class="paragraph1">
    I can help you build a product , feature or website Look through some of my work and experience! If you like what you see and have a project you need coded, don’t hestiate to contact me.
  </p>

  <ul class="icon-row">
    <li>
      <div class="tweet-connect">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/david630"><img class="tweet" src="twitter.svg" alt="twitter picture" /></a>
</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img class="med" src="medium.svg" alt="medium picture" />

    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="https://github.com/david63011"><img class="git" src="github.svg" alt="git picture" /></a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img class="angel" src="angellist.svg" alt="angelist picture" />

    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
    <section class="grid-containers">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="column1"></div>
        <div class="column2">
          <div class="project-box">
            <h1 class="project-name1">Multi-Post Stories</h1>
            <h1 class="project-name-two">Gain+Glory</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="languages">
            <ul>
              <li class="ruby">Ruby on Rails</li>
              <li class="css">css</li>
              <li class="js">JavScript</li>
              <li class="html">HTML</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="see-project-btn">See Project</button>
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
```